# Calling a method in a different class and passing an array

Tags: java, arrays, class, methods, jframe

Now i'm not sure if i've just gotten myself very confused here. I've done a lot of searching online and that doesn't seem to of helped so I figured i'd ask here. I'm essentially trying to create a coloured grid from the values in the array game[].

```
public class first
{
    public static void Newgame(){
        //variables etc
        game = new int[100];

        for(int i=0; i<100; i++) 
        {
            game[i] = 0;
            if(i==89){
                game[i] = 2;
            }
        }

      grid table1 = new grid(game[i]); // I'm trying to call the method in the other class and create the jframe grid using the values from the array game[]
    }
```

Here is the other class:

```
public class grid extends JFrame {
void game(int[] value) {           
    setSize(400, 400);
    int size = 10;


    JPanel content = new JPanel(new GridLayout(size,size));

    for (int i = 0; i < size*size; ++i) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        if(value[i]==0){
            panel.setBackground(Color.BLACK);
        }
        if(value[i]==1){
            panel.setBackground(Color.RED);
        }
        if(value[i]==2){
            panel.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        }

        content.add(panel);
    }
    add(content);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

}

Thankyou and please be patient I'm just trying to learn :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an object to grid class

```
grid table1 = new grid();
```

and call game method on that object by passing array

```
table1.game(game);
```